# PHP - Convert CP-850 to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

How do I convert [CP-850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) to UTF-8 using PHP?

**What I've found and tried**

[Gist - pedrosancao/CharsetConversion.php](https://gist.github.com/pedrosancao/9810075)

This seems like a fine solution, but since I'm working with a lot of text to change the encoding of, this is too slow. I got one process running for 40 minutes, changing the encoding of 1.5 megs of data.

[dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

I tried `dos2unix -c iso -850 data.csv`, which converts CP-850 to ASCII, but this didn't do the trick.

Comment: Maybe [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)?

Comment: This lib uses `mb_convert`. It seems ok, maybe you could try using a C exec with PHP doing a external call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `utf8_encode`, should have tried that a bit earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using iconv?
$str = iconv("CP850","UTF-8", $str);

Optionally with transliteteration (//TRANSLIT appended to the second param).

A second suggestion would be to use recode_file or recode_string; http://php.net/manual/en/ref.recode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use iconv:

```
iconv -f CP80 -t UTF-8 data.csv > data-utf8.csv
```

If you need to convert line breaks too you do:

```
iconv -f CP80 -t UTF-8 data.csv | dos2unix > data-utf8.csv
```

`dos2unix -c iso -850 data.csv` converts the file to ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1), on Windows known as CP1252.